# What is the tune played when the Strawhats stand against the CP9 in Enies Lobby?

Tags: one-piece, music

In Episode 274 (Answer Us, Robin! The Outcries of the Straw Hat Crew!!), the Strawhat Pirates assemble on the roof of the Court House. They then walk towards the Tower of Justice to join Luffy, and stand against the CP9 members, who are standing in the balcony of the Tower of Justice.

The tune played at the time sounds quite inspiring and feels great to hear. This tune runs from about 20:45 to 21:45 of the episode. Could someone please tell me the name of this tune?

[image: Strawhats stand against CP9 in Enies Lobby]

Comment: @Krazer Thanks, I forgot to add the [tag:music] tag, and was about to edit the post.

Comment: There was a [music] tag? Color me surprised. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's "I'm Here With You, Too," the same as Track #23 from [Sixth Movie's OST](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Movie_6_OST_-_Omatsuri-danshaku_to_Himitsu_no_Shima)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ov9LMCtTgqo